Как передать textfield.text в параметр URL
Я хочу получить значения слова, переданного из textfield. URL выглядит так: https://api.dictionaryapi.dev/api/v2/entries/en/word. Значения приходят в формате json. Как передать textField.text вместо word параметра? Вот код:
struct URLQuery {
    
    static func buildURL(baseURL: String, params: [String: String]) -> String? {
        guard var components = URLComponents(string: baseURL) else {
            return nil
        }
        
        let queryItems = params.map { element in
            URLQueryItem(name: element.key, value: element.value)
        }
        
        if var componentsQueryItems = components.queryItems {
            componentsQueryItems += queryItems
            components.queryItems = componentsQueryItems
        } else {
            components.queryItems = queryItems
        }

        return components.url?.absoluteString
    }

guard let word = wordTextField.text,
let urlString = URLQuery.buildURL(baseURL:  "https://api.dictionaryapi.dev", params: [
                "api":"v2",
                "entries":"en",
                "<word>": word]),
let url = URL(string: urlString)


Здесь параметры передаются в виде компонентов url, поэтому можно сделать так
struct URLQuery {
    
    static func buildURL(baseURL: String, params: String...) -> String? {
        guard var url = URL(string: baseURL) else {
            return nil
        }
        
        params.forEach {
            url.append(path: $0)
        }
        
        return url.absoluteString
    }
    
}

let text = "cat"
let urlString = URLQuery.buildURL(baseURL: "https://api.dictionaryapi.dev", 
                                  params: "api", "v2", "entries", "en", text)

Рузультат
https://api.dictionaryapi.dev/api/v2/entries/en/cat
